# How to integrate a jQuery mobile to a backend system

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, mobile, backend

So I have searched this all over the place and I get vague information, to what I think it's a pretty straightforward question.

I have built a pure jQuery mobile app, with hardcoded data. I have a backend database.

If I want to integrate the app with the database, I know that I have abstract it using php or something similar to deliver JSON objects.

The hard part for me is how to parse the JSON objects into the jQuery app.

Am I into the right path? Can someone just point me to a quick example as to how to parse a JSON object inside jQuery mobile that doesn't involve read the whole documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: From what i've seen, it's usually easier to have php actually return the html for the mobile app rather than trying to take over the built-in ajax navigation that jQM does.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Don't you think it kinda goes against the MVC rules? The mobile app should be done by a designer and the backend integration done by a php guy. I did like the answer though, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have to go against MVC, you just have to structure your MVC setup in such a way that works with JQM.